# is there any impact on existing org/projects if I create a segregated project at the same level of an org but without parent org?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hoping this is a simple question :)

I have the following structure in google cloud:

```
MyCompany - org
  homolog/ 
   project1-hml/...
  production/
   project1-prd/...
  sandbox/
   project1-sdb/
   project2/
```

If I create a project at the same level as MyCompany (so "no org"), and reuse the same billing account, so that it becomes:

```
MyCompany - org
  homolog/ 
   project1-hml/...
  production/
   project1-prd/...
  sandbox/
   project1-sdb/
   project2/
MyTestProject - project
```

Could you foresee any impact to existing things?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a project that is independent of an ORG. The project would be managed separately and would have no impact on the ORG.

Multiple projects (ORG and standalone) can be attached to a billing account. You will of course need billing account permission to attach a project to a billing account.

You can use the same identities for both the ORG and standalone projects (if desired). Just add each identity to each project's IAM. You can then manage both by either specifying the Project ID or changing the default Project ID as required.

I recommend creating a Folder under the ORG for test/experimental projects instead of standalone projects unless your goal is independence or learning.

Comment: thanks a lot @Jhon.. the goal is to create a completely unrelated POC without any chance of harming anything on the org, and at the same time using the billing structure.. does this approach make sense then? (i can't use the org because there are policies to disallow public endpoints on Cloud Run, for example)

....
i suppose also that there would be no exposure in any way between this public access and the sibling org, right? (provided no IAM is established intetionally between the two, which will be the case)

Comment: @pimguilherme - based on your comment, creating standalone projects is the right approach for you.